# socket send performance in non blocking mode

Tags: performance, sockets, udp

I'm using socket API in non blocking mode to send UDP data.  When profiling the app with google profiler I find out that 30% of the time is spent in the send API even if the app is doing other computationally expensive tasks like encrypting all the traffic. I was expecting the send API to be very cheap always when in non blocking mode.

Any reason for that?  Any way to make it more efficient?

Comment: That depends on the socket API and your code ... We will need more information.